# How to remove one property and update the model with new property

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have a JSOn model with the following properties:

```
oData:
Object
answers
:
Array(18)
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
12
:
Object
13
:
Object
14
:
Object
15
:
Object
16
:
Object
17
:
Object
length
:
18
__proto__
:
Array(0)
auditNeeded
:
false
cancelledAt
:
null
cancelledBy
:
null
dbId
:
0
description
:
null
hardeningLevelHigh
:
false
lastSavedAt
:
null
lastSavedBy
:
null
manager
:

projectId
:
null
scenario
:
null
secConceptComment
:
null
secConceptNeededAfterValidation
:
false
secConceptNeededSelfAssessment
:
false
secConceptStatus
:
null
status
:
null
submittedAt
:
null
submitter
:
null
```

As you can see I am getting an array of asnsers in the first property where each answer has a structure like:

```
oData:
Object
answers
:
Array(18)
0
:
Object
active
:
false
answer
:
true
explanation
:
"Tooltip 1"
feedback
:
null
id
:
0
question
:
"Is personal data being processed?"
questionId
:
7
versionId
:
0
```

I need to delete the above answer array from my model and include a new array with the same answer structure in the existing model.

1) How do i delete the answer object from my model.

2) How do i include my newly created answer model in the same model.

Thanks !!

Comment: please add the object in [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 0):

For deleting answer property simply do this

```
delete myObj.answers;
```

Adding new object in array is also quit simple

```
myObj["answer"] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/vbhakrfb/

```js
var data = {answer: [
  {"a": "A"},
  {"b": "B"},
  {"c": "C"}
]};

console.log("Before deleting: ", data);

delete data.answer;

console.log("After deleting: ", data);

data.answer = [
  {"newa" : "A"},
  {"newb" : "B"}
];

console.log("Added new Answer: ", data);
```